# Is there a method to add constraints within conditional statements in Z3py?

Tags: z3py, subset-sum

I am trying to solve the subset sum problem using the Z3 solver with a slight difference. The sum elements in the subset should be 0, but the elements should be chosen in such a fashion that no two consecutive elements are chosen.

For eg:

```
set = [-7, -3, -2, 5, 8, -2]
set_len = len(set)
vars = [Int('vars_%d' % i) for i in range(set_len)]
s = Solver()
rt = []

for i in range(set_len):
    rt.append(vars[i]*set[i])
    s.add(Or(vars[i]==0, vars[i]==1))

s.add(sum(vars)>=1)
s.add(sum(rt)==0)

temp = Bool('temp')
for i in range(set_len):
    temp = vars[i] == 1
    if temp == True:
        s.add(vars[i+1]==0)

if s.check()==False:
    print("unsat")
    
m=s.model()
print(m)
```

The part of the code where I am facing issue is this:

```
temp = Bool('temp')
for i in range(set_len):
    temp = vars[i] == 1
    if temp == True:
        s.add(vars[i+1]==0)
```

The problem is with the 'if' condition.

One of the solutions that I get is:

```
[vars_3 = 1,
 vars_0 = 0,
 vars_1 = 1,
 vars_4 = 0,
 vars_2 = 1,
 vars_5 = 0]
```

If vars_1 = 1, then vars_2 should **not** be equal to 1.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use booleans to represent the picks, and make sure that no two-consecutive picks are enabled at the same time. Something like:

```py
from z3 import *

inp  = [-7, -3, -2, 5, 8, -2]
pick = [Bool('pick_%d' %i) for i in range(len(inp))]

s = Solver()

# make sure we pick at least one element
s.add(Or(pick))

# make sure no consecutive elements are picked:
for i, j in zip(pick, pick[1:]):
    s.add(Not(And(i, j)))

# make sure picked elements sum to 0:
total = 0
for i, p in enumerate(pick):
    total = total + If(p, inp[i], 0)
s.add(total == 0)

r = s.check()
if r == sat:
   m = s.model()
   for i, p in enumerate(pick):
       if m.eval(p): print(inp[i])
else:
    print("Solver said: %s" % r)
```

When I run this, I get:

```
-3
5
-2
```

which satisfies your constraints.

Comment: Glad to hear! The customary thing to do is to “officially accept the answer,” by clicking on the check mark, which signals to other readers that the solution works should they have a similar problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! I'm new here. Done!

Comment: No worries. Welcome to stack-overflow.